# createjs.Shadow alpha

Tags: alpha, shadow, createjs

Can the alpha of a drop shadow created with createjs.Shadow be controlled independently of the object it's attached to? I tried, simply:

```
myObject.shadow = new createjs.Shadow("#000000",200,200,15);
myObject.shadow.alpha=0.2;
```

But that's a no go. Can't find anything in the API docs, but those are all pretty damn confusing to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the alpha of a shadow by adjusting the alpha of the fill color it uses. For example:

```
myObject.shadow = new createjs.Shadow("rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",200,200,15);
```

It might also be worth taking a look at `Graphics.getRGB()`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've always stuck to using hex values for color before, so it never occured to me to try this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "alpha" on a shadow.

It looks like the properties of the Shadow class are not properly doc'd. The settable properties are the same as the parameters used when initializing the class:

- color
- offsetX
- offsetY
- blur

http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Shadow.html

I will look at fixing the documentation. Thanks for the heads up! I am curious why you find the documentation confusing, other than that issue. We have gone to great lengths to create thorough, readable documentation, and I am sorry to hear you are having issues.

Comment: Well, this Shadow class is a good example. Though I'm not suggesting that the documentation cater to the lowest common denominator,but I keep catching little things that would throw fresh starters off. For example, the documentation for tweening, fails to state that _createjs._ needs to be placed in front of Tween, else you get errors.

I found documentation here (http://docs.createjs.jp/EaselJS_docs-0.3.2/Graphics.html#method_beginRadialGradientFill) to be far more descriptive and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this note, and you are correct, we had no idea the main description for TweenJS still had the (really old) syntax that didn't include the `createjs.` namespace in the examples. I will get this fixed ASAP, and we will do another pass on the classes to see if they could benefit from more examples.

Comment: I updated the TweenJS docs to ensure the namespace is shown in the examples. Thanks! http://createjs.com/Docs/TweenJS/modules/TweenJS.html